# Setting up Inseego/AT&T/Novatel USB800 USB Wireless Modem on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, usb-modem, 4g, wwan

I'm attempting to get inseego/at&t's USB800 wireless modem to work on my Ubuntu 20.04 box.

However, upon plugging it in, looks like the Linux host cannot be properly initialize it. The User Manual for USB800 USB WAN indicates that it is Linux compatible, but I am getting the following error logs:

```
kernel: [4627412.526593] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 45
kernel: [4627412.526654] rndis_host 2-1.3:1.0 enx0015ff036177: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:42:00.3-1.3, RNDIS device
kernel: [4627412.850617] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 46 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [4627412.965436] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1410, idProduct=b020, bcdDevice= 3.18
kernel: [4627412.965437] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: [4627412.965438] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB800
kernel: [4627412.965439] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Novatel Wireless
kernel: [4627412.965439] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
networkd-dispatcher[1394]: WARNING:Unknown index 164605 seen, reloading interface list
kernel: [4627413.051430] cdc_ether 2-1.3:1.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:42:00.3-1.3, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:15:ff:03:61:77
kernel: [4627413.053699] hid-generic 0003:1410:B020.282E1: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Device [Novatel Wireless USB800] on usb-0000:42:00.3-1.3/input2
systemd-udevd[2240731]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
systemd-udevd[2240731]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
kernel: [4627413.057187] cdc_ether 2-1.3:1.0 enx0015ff036177: renamed from eth0
systemd-networkd[1266]: eth0: Interface name change detected, eth0 has been renamed to enx0015ff036177.
networkd-dispatcher[1394]: WARNING:Unknown index 164605 seen, reloading interface list
systemd-udevd[2240731]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
ModemManager[1515]: <info> [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:08.1/0000:42:00.3/usb2/2-1/2-1.3': not supported by any plugin
```

Another strange symptom is that the associated network device 'enx0015ff036177' is disappearing from `ip link` results every 10 seconds or so.

The 'modem-manager' is also not seeing any plugged in devices here.

```
mmcli -L
No modems were found
```

What seems to be the problem here? Thank you in advance for your advice!

Comment: You may want to investigate with the maker of the device what versions of Linux. Many will say that something works with Linux but there are many many many versions. Also it may be referring to some older version.

Comment: According to this (from AT&T) themselves) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_dgiF1xHgo and as expected this device ISN'T to be managed by any old "modem" software. Instead it should create a standard "Ethernet over USB" connection and then be managed by accessing its own "web server" from any browser (and of, course, this is OS agnostic).